Is there a theory of completions of semirings similar to $I$-adic completions of rings?
Let $L = \text{Con } (\mathbb{N}, 0, +) \setminus \Delta$ be the lattice of monoid congruences on the naturals, excluding the trivial congruence. As it happens, every $\theta \in L$ is the meet of some finite combination of $\Theta(0, p^k)$ and $\Theta(k, k + 1)$, where $\Theta(a, b)$ represents the smallest congruence identifying $a$ and $b$, $p$ is prime, and $k > 0$. These are precisely the meet-irreducible congruences.
The $p$-adics, as a profinite group, can be constructed as the inverse limit of
$$\mathbb{N}/\Theta(0, p) \leftarrow \mathbb{N}/\Theta(0, p^2) \leftarrow \mathbb{N}/\Theta(0, p^3) \leftarrow \ldots$$
where I now abbreviate $(\mathbb{N}, 0, +)$ as $\mathbb{N}$ and the arrows represent the natural projection maps by refining the quotient. This gave me the idea for constructing the """$1$-adics""":
$$\mathbb{N}/\Theta(1, 2) \leftarrow \mathbb{N}/\Theta(2, 3) \leftarrow \mathbb{N}/\Theta(3, 4) \leftarrow \ldots$$
where you have to bear with me for the very silly name I have encased in triple attack quotes. Anyway, this ends up being isomorphic to $(\mathbb{N} \cup \infty, 0, +)$, with the topology being the interval topology, which in this case is the stone space of the finite-cofinite boolean algebra on a countable set. Further, this is a profinite monoid (well, you don't see that every day, do you?) in the sense that the monoid's operation is continuous on this profinite topology. We can also do this exact same thing to $(\mathbb{N}, 0, +, 1, \times)$, the semiring, because the quotients of this semiring happen to be the same as quotients of the monoid $(\mathbb{N}, 0, +)$, and thus get the exact same results, but with multiplication now defined in a similar manner.
This construction looks very similar to the completion of a ring defined by the filtration $R = I^0 \supseteq I^1 \supseteq I^2 \supseteq \ldots$ often called $I$-adic completion. (As far as I'm aware- I'm not very well educated on the terminology often used here.) The main difference is that it makes no sense to speak of a power of a congruence. Is there a way to think about $\Theta(k, k+1)$ in the same way we think about $\Theta(0, p^k)$? I only have a few leads- the Boolean semiring seems to be connected to tropical geometry, so one of my friends has suggested calling this congruence the "tropical prime" $\tau$, to distinguish it from $\mathbb{F}_1$ math, which has a distinct flavor, despite the superficial similarity. I'm also aware of the concept of a profinite completion for any algebraic structure and it turns out that the profinite completion of $\mathbb{N}$ is $\mathbb{N} \sqcup \mathbb{\hat{Z}}$, with square cup as in disjoint union, not coproduct: we add/multiply $n \in \mathbb{N}$ with $x \in \mathbb{\hat{Z}}$ by converting $n$ into an element of $\mathbb{\hat{Z}}$ first. Finally, I tried googling "semiring completion" but it seems this term already has an unrelated (or related? I'm not sure) meaning in current semiring literature. It also primarily concerns ordered semirings instead of more number-theoretic ones.
Note: I edited this post to be clearer and less click-bait-y from its original form.

Probably unrelated to your construction, but here is a paper with a "dream of 1-adics".

@Aurel thank you for this note. Yeah, I should perhaps have avoided the $\mathbb{F}_1$ language, because this is probably more of a different phenomenon- I just don't have a good name for it. I often jokingly call the semi-ring of truth values $\mathbb{F_1}$, but its category of finite dimensional modules is $\mathbf{Rel}^{f.g.}$ and true $\mathbb{F_1}$ should have something like the category of finite sets with partial bijections, so these are two separate things.

Actually, I just remembered how I once saw that this is more related to tropical geometry, so I will edit my post with this information.

As a fun fact, your "$1$-adics" correspond to base 1 numbers with a possibly infinite amount of digits in exactly the same sense that the $p$-adics correspond to base-$p$. I asked a related question on MSE some time ago. Sadly it seems that the theory is not as nice as for the integers: in the case of $\mathbb{Z}$ every inverse limit can be decomposed as a product of $p$-adics, but there isn't an analogous result in the case of $\mathbb{N}$.

@pregunton I just had a conversation about this on discord... this is either a really funny coincidence or a paraphrase of the main point (from the discord conversation). Either way, good for it to be recorded on this post.
Oh yea, also good link, that is indeed my question but with a lot more specificity, so I will give it a look.

@pregunton your MSE post is more interesting than I expected, and I already expected it to be interesting to me. I've also thought about total exponential operations on semirings, although only briefly, and never got anywhere interesting. I am tempted to bounty your question because it deserves more upvotes than this relatively bare-bones question I've asked. I will think about it first, though, to see if I can't answer it myself.

Regarding the notion of 'power of a congruence', something just occurred to me. In the integer case the ideal $n\mathbb{Z}$ can be taken as a generating equivalence class, such that all other equivalence classes in the congruence are of the form $x+(n\mathbb{Z})$. Note that the powers $n^k\mathbb{Z}$ of this ideal are given by iterations of the function $x\mapsto nx$. There is similarly a (this time unique) generating equivalence class for the congruence $\Theta(a,b)$, namely $\alpha \mathbb{N} + \beta$ with $\alpha = b-a, \beta=a$.

A sensible definition of "power" would then be in terms of iterations of the affine function $x\mapsto \alpha x + \beta$ (these are the "powers" that I use to define the inverse limit for $\mathbb{N}_{\alpha,\beta}$ in my MSE question). In particular the $k$th "power" of $\mathbb{N} + 1$ is $\mathbb{N} + k$, which corresponds to the congruence $\Theta(k,k+1)$ as expected.
